# Is it possible to lock an android app in portrait mode only on phones with cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, device, screen-orientation

I would like my app to support only the following orientations:

- On phones: portrait or reverse-portrait
- On tablets: portrait, reverse-portrait, landscape, reverse-landscape

I am finding a lot of information about how to do this in an Android application, but not in a cordova application. Is there no way to do this without having to modify the Java code?

I have already solved this problem on iOS by adding the following to my project's plist file:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
  <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

The plist file is created by cordova and it's an xml file, so it's easy to make a script that adds these configurations every time I build.

But on Android, there seems to be only one property for this in AndroidManifest.xml which applies to both phones and tablets. What is the cordova way of doing this?

Comment: I'd like to know if you figured this out, I need a similar solution and using the cordova-yoik-screenorientation plugin did not seem to work for me. I see no way to do this via built-in cordova properties.

Comment: @jflay Indeed, what I do now is modify the java files created by cordova when the project is created.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to lock an android app in portrait mode only on phone with Cordova/PhoneGap app

at first, open your Cordova/PhoneGap app directory, then find config.xml file add this syntax`<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />`

and more info: [Config.xml - Apache Cordova, preference](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/#preference)

Answer (score -3):

its pretty straight forward, the most easy way is to define this by hand...

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.yourApplicationy"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ...
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        ...
</activity>
```

Define this manually in your application's manifest file. Cordova WON'T override your changes!

Comment: How do I set a different orientation for tablets than for phones with this method?